# How to resize meta images in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have images in `.raw / .mhd` format. The `DimSize` of the images are different. Is there any way to resize `metaimage` format images? I am using matlab to read the images.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have read the image as an 2D array, the resizing can be done using an interpolation technique for the regular grids. A good tool to do that is the class [griddedInterpolant](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddedinterpolant.html).

In the case you have Image Processing Toolbox, you may use the function `imresize()`.

Comment: Would you please provide an example for how to resize by griddedInterpolant?